# Read part files from hdfs into data frame using pySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, partitioning

I have multiple files stored in a hdfs location as follows

> /user/project/202005/part-01798
>
> /user/project/202005/part-01799

There are 2000 such part files. Each file is of the format

```
{'Name':'abc','Age':28,'Marks':[20,25,30]} 
{'Name':...}
```

and so on . I have 2 questions

```
1) How to check whether these are multiple files or multiple partitions of the same file
2) How to read these in a data frame using pyspark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As these files are in one directory, and these are named as part-xxxxx files, so you can safely assume these are multiple part files of the same dataset. If these are partitions, they should be saved like this /user/project/date=202005/*
2. You can specify the dir "/user/project/202005" as input for spark like below assuming these are csv files

```
df = spark.read.csv('/user/project/202005/*',header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

Comment: ```spark.read.json``` did the trick for me . But thanks for pointing me in the right direction and clarifying the first question